# Alternative for delaying filter requests for Filter.filter() since Delayer interface is hidden?

Tags: android, android-adapterview

For an adapter I've written I would like to have a small delay for the filter (to avoid starting a filter operation on each repeated keys and wait a fraction of a second until the user slows down his/her typing since the list to filter is potentially quite large and and filter operation will take a couple of 100s ms).

Looking at the source for the Filter class it provides exactly that opportunity since it has a public Delayer interface which is used to get a delay time when posting a message (via `sendMessageDelayed()` ) to execute the actual filter on a separate worker thread (to get off the main UI thread). It also deletes any previous message still in the queue that has not yet been executed (due to the delay).

So far so good. Seems perfectly simple to just implement that interface and extend the Filter class.

However, for some reason the function to set the Delayer is annotated as `@hide` so strictly speaking this should not be used and could be removed in any future SDK updates. Which means I would be stupid to rely on it.

What is the best way to solve this without having to re-implement the complete Filter class yourself (which seems a silly thing to do)?

I guess one alternative option would be to setup and use my own handler thread and create a delayed message to call the filter function but it seems a bit heavy handed?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think the best solution to this is to embrace the open source nature of Android, and do exactly what you (almost) suggest:

> re-implement the complete Filter class yourself (which seems a silly
>   thing to do)

Since the `Delay` related code has been in production for years, it should be safe to use.

I just copied the `Filter` code from API 23 and removed the `@hide` annotations. I renamed it to prevent import clashes and it seems to be working.

---

I added it to Github for easy reuse in later projects:

- [mobiRic / DelayFilter.java on Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/mobiRic/f6c789fa8fa31c5f0ad3bc1490c7d184)